# jQuery sortable from vertical to horizontal

Tags: jquery, css

I want to be able to add words from a vertical list to a horizontal one using jQuery's sortable. 
Going from the horizontal to the vertical works as expected, but going from vertical to the horizontal, it works poorly. It makes the words jump down and it is very hard to place the word in the desired location. It works fine if I add the css property float:left to the #oates p selector but I want to avoid this as I want to keep the list as vertical.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.
code  and fiddle below

html

```
<div id="sortable" class="connectedSortable">
 <p>The </p>
 <p>dog </p>
 <p>ate </p>
</div>

<div id="oates" class="connectedSortable">
 <p>green </p>
 <p>grass </p>
 <p>for </p>
 <p>lunch </p>
</div>
```

css

```
#sortable p {
float: left;
padding: 2px;
}

#sortable  {
padding-left: 20px;
border: solid black 2px;
height: 100px; 
}

#oates {
margin: 20px;
color: red; 
padding-left: 20px;
border: solid blue 1px;

} 

#oates p {
  /* float:left;*/

}
```

jQuery

```
$(function() {

$( "#sortable, #oates" ).sortable({

  connectWith: ".connectedSortable"

}).disableSelection();

});
```

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/9MTq6/

Comment: I don't understand the desired behavior. And you say you have problems going from vertical to the horizontal, but then you say you want to keep the list as vertical?

Comment: Desired behaviour is; the user can select any word from a vertical list and add it to the sentence (in the desired position) above (the horizontal list).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use floating elements with `clear:both` to keep the list as vertical, and set a different `overflow` than `visible` to `#oates`:

```
#oates {
    overflow:auto; /*or hidden*/     
} 
#oates p {
   float:left;
   clear:both;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/9MTq6/3/)